# Using a list parameter in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to be able to set an SSRS parameter to contain multiple values.

In TSQL, I can have a `where` clause that states:

```
where Attribute in ('Value1', 'Value', 'Value3')
```

What I need is in SSRS to have:

```
where Attribute in (@Attribute)
```

Where I am getting hung up is how to format the parameter value expression so that SQL sees it as: `'Value1', 'Value', 'Value3'`

I have had some luck making the `where` clause look at only the first value, but I need it to look at all 3. How would I format the expression to do that?

I would just allow it to accept multiple values, and check each value individually, but I need the drop down list  to have groups. So, if the user selects GroupA, the `where` clause uses: `IN ('Value1', Value2')` and if the user selects GroupB, the `where` clause uses a different list for the `IN`.

Hopefully it's just a matter of formatting the expression correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you didn't have the requirements about groups, this wouldn't be an issue since all you need is to make your parameter a multi-valued one, and on your dataset query do `WHERE Attribute in (@Attribute)`. But taking that requirement into account, the only way I can think of, is to have two multi-valued parameters: `@Group` and `@Attribute`. You'll need to make `@Attribute` not visible and create a dataset to populate it. That dataset would be something like this:

```
SELECT Attribute
FROM Attributes
WHERE Group IN (@Group)
```

And create another dataset for your report data:

```
SELECT <all your data>
FROM YourTable
WHERE Attribute IN (@Attribute)
```

Comment: I am doing this, and it seems to be passing the correct values to the parameter, but the report is still looking only at the first value from the list.